# Angular static input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, static

I have an Angular beginners question:

I have data in json and from this I want to make one particular webpage.
Mister Smith gets a link from me, and he must see his info, without he need to enter his name in a inputfield or need to check a checkbox

With inputfield or checkbox all work fine for me, but what i need is 
`value1 = 'Smith'`

So i get in the `ng-repeat` a static value for `value1`

I can make it work with a checkbox, but I don't want the checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="value1" 
     ng-true-value="Smith" ng-false-value=""> Mister Smith <br/>

<ng-repeat="name in names | filter:value1 " >
<b>{{name.firstname}}</b>
```

In what way I can give `value1` a static value within my html?

Answer (score 0):

use `{{value1}}`.

So the code will look like:

```
{{value1}} <br/>

<ng-repeat="name in names | filter:value1 " >
<b>{{name.firstname}}</b>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but this don't work for what I need.
I have in json a database, which contains some info about mister smith. What I need is a webpage for mister smith, without he need to select his name somehow.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use ng-init, http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit
I'm not sure if you have to assign the filter to a variable first, but you could attempt something like

```
<ng-init="value1 = Smith" ng-repeat="name in names | filter:value1 " >
```

However, as the warning clearly states in the documentation it's better to do this in your controller.

**Update**: Based on your edit.

```
.controller('SomeController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    // Assuming you get your data using $http 
    $http.get('/some/resource').success(function (data) {
        // Assuming data.name is "Mr Smith"
        $scope.filter.filterOn = data.name;
    });
}]);
```

And then,

```
<ng-repeat="name in names | filter:filter.filterOn " >
```

Comment: Thank you KG, i've tried both methodes. The first one don't work, the second one does, but it's not what I need. I want just one controller and multiple webpages need to grab certain data, from this, depending on the webpage which calls the controller. I've found something with 'limitTo' which can filter limited by a pre defined text.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure if I understand your goal here. But am I to understand that you solved it?

Comment: I got another solution, what work for me:
<input ng-init="value1='Smith'" ng-model="value1">